# For Docker Netrworking: Why (what scenario(s)) would you not use just "--network host" for "Host" mode networking?

Tags: docker, docker-network

This is a followup to an earlier question that I had asked, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72046646/does-docker-persist-the-resolv-conf-from-the-physical-etc-resolv-conf-in-the-co".

I've been testing with containers on 2 different machines, and using "--network host" and from that earlier thread in that case it is using a default "Host" mode network named "host"(?).

Since with "host" mode networking, the container and the app inside the container are basically on the same IP as the physical host where the container is running, under what (example) scenarios would you actually want to create a named "host" mode network and then have container use that named "host" mode network?

What would the advantages/differences be between using the custom/named "host" mode network vs. just using "--network host"?

It seems like both situations (using "--network host" vs. "create network xyz" where xyz is a named host network, and then doing the container "docker run --network xyz" would functionally be the same?

Sorry for the newbie question :( and thanks again in advance.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a host-mode named network, and if you did, there'd be no reason to use it.  If you need host networking – and you almost certainly don't – use `docker run --net host` or Compose `network_mode: host`.

But really, you don't need host networking.

With standard Docker networking, you can use `docker run -p` to publish individual ports out to the host.  You get a choice to not publish a given port, and can remap the port.  This also means that if, for example, you're running three services each with their own PostgreSQL server, there's no conflict over the single port 5432.

The cases where you actually need it are pretty limited.  If an application listens on a very large number of ports or it doesn't listen on a predictable port then the `docker run -p` mechanism doesn't work well.  If it needs to actively manage the host network then it needs to be given access to it (and it might be better run outside a container).  If you've hard-coded `localhost` in your application, then in Docker your database isn't usually there (configuration via environment variables would be better).

Comment: hi - David - I should've mentioned that the scenario (there are several, but this is one of them) was where we had multiple (physical) docker hosts and were running both "native" (== not containerized) Springboot app instances AND containerized instances of the same app on each of the physical machines.  We actually initially tried "bride" network for the dockerized containers, and used -p to map the ports to avoid port conflict with the native Springboot instances (again, running on the same physical machines).

Comment: The app uses Hazelcast clustering, and we ran into several problems (some which we haven't been able to replicate again) with UnknownHostExceptions and cluster members leaving the cluster randomly. 

We then switched to using "--network host" and also our app can take a param for the listen port, so we ran the docker container with that param so that the containerized instance was using a different port than Springboot instance, and that config has been stable so far.

Comment: Your response on the earlier question helped us get the networking working with "--network host" but I was just curious if there was some advantage to using a named host network.  I may've been misinterpreting something you said in that other thread... about the "--network host" using default or something like that, which kind of made me think that it was possible to have a named "host" network.